# Synchronously execute NodeJS CLI commands - unable to place/ create new files on the close event of child_process exec (nesting execute commands)

Tags: javascript, node.js, command-line-interface

I want to create a CLI tool which:

1) Asks the user for a project name 
2) Calls the `npx create-react-app [user input name]` 
3) Once this is completed, go into that folder and remove the old `.gitignore` file 
4) Once that `.gitignore` file is removed, create a new one - cloned/ copied/ downloaded from a github repository.

So far it works perfectly up until step 4). The `.gitignore` file gets removed just fine but the new one isn't being downloaded/ placed there.

Here is my complete code:

```js
const chalk = require("chalk");
const figlet = require("figlet");
const exec = require("child_process").exec;
const ora = require("ora");
const fs = require("fs");

// create an input interface
const readline = require("readline").createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout
});

const spinner = ora();

// 1. clear the console
process.stdout.write("\x1Bc");

// 2. print some fancy text
console.log(
  chalk.green(figlet.textSync("My CLI Tool", { horizontalLayout: "full" }))
);

// 3. ask user for project name
readline.question(`What is your project name? `, name => {
  console.log(`\nCreating a React project named: ${name} ...`);

  // 4. Create a create-react-app project
  spinner.start();
  exec(`npx create-react-app ${name}`).on("close", () => {
    spinner.stop();
    console.log(`\nProject ${name} created...`);

    // 5. Remove the existing .gitignore file from that project folder
    console.log(`\nRemoving old ${name}/.gitignore file...`);
    spinner.start();
    fs.unlink(`./${name}/.gitignore`, err => {
      if (err) {
        console.error(err);
        return;
      }

      //file removed
      spinner.stop();

      // 6. Place new .gitignore file in that project directory
      console.log(`\nPlacing new gitignore file...`);
      spinner.start();

      exec(
        `wget -O ./${name}/.gitignore https://raw.githubusercontent.com/github/gitignore/master/Node.gitignore`
      ).on("close", () => {
        spinner.stop();
        console.log(`\nNew ${name}/.gitignore created...`);
      });
    });
  });

  readline.close();
});
```

I'm not getting any console errors. 
I can see `New test/.gitignore created...` in my console when the process is completed, but not before it - which leads me to believe I've nested everything correctly and it's all working synchronously.

The command

```
wget -O ./test/.gitignore https://raw.githubusercontent.com/github/gitignore/master/Node.gitignore
```

works as long as the `./test/` directory exists - which it should do when the program hits that line of code.

Am I missing something? How can I create this functionality? I believe I'm missing something really trivial but cannot seem to figure it out.

And is there a nicer, more concise way of creating this CLI tool? Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: looks like you forgot to add some more `on(...)` handling to your exec. Assuming "close" happens, without adding an "error" handler just in case, is usually being a little too optimistic in your assumptions about what the computer will do =)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans What?

Comment: If your `exec` for wget is not doing what you expect, then rewrite your exec call so that you see what it does. Even if your final code won't keep that change. At the very least, give `exec` access to stdin/stdout/stderr so you can see what it's doing. (the example for which is listed in the `exec` docs over on https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback)

Comment: Given your recent [CR post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/237879/120114) it appears you switched to using `https.get()` instead of `wget`. Do you still want to try using `wget`?